# Filter numbers in conditionally chosen rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of an index with date-objects and a column "PSM" that is filled with Strings. These Strings can be of various types or NaN. One of the possible format is "5 %", "3%, "%3" and all kinds of similar formats.

Goal is to filter the rows that include a %-sign in PSM and replace the value with only the number as an integer. So "5 %" shall change to 5, "%3" and "3%" to 3 and so forth.

I have tried various things:

1. Using a for-loop to iterate over the rows and filter on `%` using `in`, then trying to change the value using `int(filter(str.isdigit, string))`, but I cannot wrap my head around how to actually change x.

   ```
   for x in df.PSM:
       if '%' in x:
           do "int(filter(str.isdigit, string))" to x
   ```
2. Also, for-loops always make me suspicious and I searched for more pythonic ways to do this. I found various possibilities but could not get one of them to work.
   `test['%' in test.PSM] = ?` is one of them, but I do not know how to get the `int(filter(str.isdigit, string))` to work in the right side.
   Something like `df.loc['%' in df.PSM, int(filter(str.isdigit, df.PSM))]` did not work, too.

So I have two questions.
How do I fill the body of the for-loop to act like I want it to? 
And, as I feel like there has to be a more elegant way, what are the alternative, possibly more pythonic ways to filter the numbers?

Edit with Exampledataframe:

```
data = ["% 5", "5%, ", "3%", "k52%"]
col = ["PSM"]
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(4), periods=4, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=col)
```

This looks like that:

```
            PSM
2017-07-08   % 5
2017-07-09  5%, 
2017-07-10    3%
2017-07-11  k52%
```

I want it to be like that:

```
            PSM
2017-07-08  5
2017-07-09  5
2017-07-10  3
2017-07-11  52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with parameter `na=False` for boolean mask and then use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) numbers only or [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) / [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for replace non numbers to empty string:

```
data = ["% 5", "5%, ", "3%", "k52%", "aa", "ade3", np.nan]
col = ["PSM"]
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(4), periods=7, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=col)
print (df)
             PSM
2017-07-09   % 5
2017-07-10  5%, 
2017-07-11    3%
2017-07-12  k52%
2017-07-13    aa
2017-07-14  ade3
2017-07-15   NaN
```

---

```
mask = df['PSM'].str.contains('%', na=False)
df.loc[mask, 'PSM'] = df.loc[mask, 'PSM'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
             PSM
2017-07-09     5
2017-07-10     5
2017-07-11     3
2017-07-12    52
2017-07-13    aa
2017-07-14  ade3
2017-07-15   NaN

mask = df['PSM'].str.contains('%', na=False)
df.loc[mask, 'PSM'] = df.loc[mask, 'PSM'].str.replace('(\D+)', '')
print (df)
             PSM
2017-07-09     5
2017-07-10     5
2017-07-11     3
2017-07-12    52
2017-07-13    aa
2017-07-14  ade3
2017-07-15   NaN

mask = df['PSM'].str.contains('%', na=False)
df.loc[mask, 'PSM'] = df.loc[mask, 'PSM'].replace('(\D+)', '', regex=True)
print (df)
             PSM
2017-07-09     5
2017-07-10     5
2017-07-11     3
2017-07-12    52
2017-07-13    aa
2017-07-14  ade3
2017-07-15   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re

data = ["% 5", "5%, ", "3%", "k52%"]
strp = re.compile(r'\d+')
new_data = []
for item in data:
    m = strp.search(item)
    if m:
        new_data.append(m.group(0))

col = ["PSM"]
todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(4), periods=4, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, index=index, columns=col)
```

Comment: What do I have to fill in for `string`?

Comment: It's there in your Question. Ask yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
df.loc['%' in df.PSM,'PSM'] = df.loc['%' in df.PSM,'PSM'].replace('%','')
```

Edit:

Fixed version:

```
df.loc[df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'] = 
df.loc[df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'].str.replace(r'\D+',''‌​)
```

Comment: If I try this, I get an error. `KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'` Unfortunately I do not really understand what you are doing, so I do not know how to fix this. Can you explain it?

Comment: It's hard to test it without an example I can reproduce - what about df.loc[ df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'] = df.loc[df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'].replace('%','') ??

Comment: I'm trying to use .loc to slice a subset of your df using a boolean mask where PSM string contains '%', and then replace this slice with itself with applied .replace method

Comment: If I understand correctly, you try to eliminate the % - but unfortunately that is not everything I need to do, because there can be other characters, like for example whitespaces that I need to remove, too. So simply replacing '%' with '' does not do the trick.

Comment: Now I get `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`, but there are no NaN-Values in the dataframe (I have used fillna in the line above)

Comment: I have added an example-dataframe to the question

Comment: df.loc[df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'] = df.loc[df.PSM.str.contains('%'),'PSM'].str.replace(r'\D+','')  this worked for me on the example above. It should replace all non-numeric characters in those strings.